# Finding parameters for function to be integrable

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, riemann-integration

Here's the function:

$h(x) = \begin{cases}
    \cot x   & \text{if $x \in [-\pi/2,0)-\{-\pi/3\}$}\\
    p & \text{if $x=-\pi/3$}\\
    q & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$

Find the value of parameter $p$ (if it exists) so that $h$ is integrable on $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, -\frac{\pi}{4}\right]$.
Find the value of p for which function h(x) has primitive function on (- pi/2, 0)
Find the values of p and q for which h(x) is integrable on [-pi/2, 0]

I'll be honest here. I have no idea how to do this type of problems. I don't know how to do it. I have these 4 theorems:

1) If f is integrable, then f is bounded

2) If f is defined, bounded and has finite number of disconuities, then f is integrable

3) If f is monotonous, then f is integrable

4) If f is continuous then f is integrable

The thing is, I can solve integrals and no, I'm not lazy and came here just to get a quick solution. This is not the only problem of this type that I've stumbled upon. I just **don't know** how to solve this type of problems. I don't know how to come up with parameters or functions that can work for given conditions. That's why I'm hoping that I can find something out based on this example so that I can learn to do it.

The best thing would be if there could be some sort of "blueprint" I could guide myself when coming up with the solution for this type of problems but I guess there ain't one. Anyway, if someone can give me a help regarding this problem and similar type problems that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The domain of $\cot x$ is $\mathbb R\setminus \{n\pi:n\in\mathbb Z\}$. We also have that $\cot x$ has a vertical asymptote at $x=0$ and $\cot(-\frac{\pi}{3})=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: I edited your post a bit to show how you can use mathjax formatting to make it a bit more readable and encourage you to apply this on the rest of your question.